# Spring boot アプリケーションでAndroidのブラウザからAndroidアプリを立ち上げたい

Tags: android, java, spring, spring-boot

AndroidアプリからブラウザでローカルPCのSpring bootアプリを開いて、そのSpring bootのアプリから再びAndroidアプリに戻ってくるという実装をしています。

そこで下記のようにAndroid Manifestにintent-filterを記述し

Android-Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".presentation.SigninActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_signin"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="callback"
              android:path="/param"
              android:scheme="myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Spring側(@Controller内)で下記のようにリダイレクトします。実際はmyappではなく別の名前です。

Spring bootリダイレクト部分

```
return "redirect:myapp://callback/param?hoge=aaa&huga=bbb";
```

しかし、AndroidのブラウザのSpring boot上で下記エラーによりAndroidアプリに戻って来られません。

エラー

```
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

おそらくSpring bootの問題かと考えられましたがどのようにリダイレクトさせればAndroidアプリに戻ることができるのでしょうか。

実行環境

Android: 
Genymotion(Android 5.0 Custom Phone)